# Get PublishingPageContent rendered when using Rest Api

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have recently encountered this problem on SharePoint:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221059/get-publishingpagecontent-rendered-when-using-rest-api

Since there is no provided answer for the question, I was just wondering if someone else has maybe solved this problem or found a workaround for it in the meantime?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sowmyancs/2008/03/15/create-publishing-pages-in-portal-sites-programmatically-and-add-it-into-a-specific-folders-inside-the-pages-library/

Publishing the pages (as listed in the code above) leaves the pages in a "pending" approval status.  To programatically approve the pages as well
 – just use the Publish and Approve methods of the SPFile class:

publishingPage.CheckIn(checkInComment);

SPFile pageFile = publishingPage.ListItem.File;

```
       pageFile.Publish(checkInComment);

       pageFile.Approve(checkInComment);
```

Listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.description.aspx